# selenium python css selector can't find element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
video = "YzmI5F_Yu1o"

driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank');")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/v/" + video)
title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink')
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\playlist.py", line 36, in <module>
    add_yt("YzmI5F_Yu1o")
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\playlist.py", line 33, in add_yt
    title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink')
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 498, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

basically, it says that there is no element with the css selector .ytp-title-link.yt-uix-sessionlink, even though there clearly is.

element I am trying to return;

```html
<a class="ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink" target="_blank" data-
    sessionlink="feature=player-title" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?
    v=YzmI5F_Yu1o">Marco Borsato - Mooi (official video)</a>
```

Comment: can you add your HTML code snippet also

Comment: I will do that now :)

Comment: Accessing link https://www.youtube.com/v/YzmI5F_Yu1o is directly downloading the file. What do you actually want to do? What are your manual steps?

Comment: it doesn't directly download the file for me (keep in mind I'm using chromedriver), it shows the video whilst it it paused. I am trying to retrieve the video title

Comment: This opens a embed video with full screen and no html as such, just the embed tag and hence no CSS element and it should error out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch to `embed` element just like to `iframe` and get required text:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//embed'))
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-sessionlink="feature=player-title"]').text
```

Comment: Though this technically works, it's more of a bandade solution to the question.

Comment: @Andersson - How to you get to know that frame name is //embed?

Comment: @ShubhamJain, it's not an iframe name, but tag name

Comment: @Andersson - So do we also require switching to embed tag each time to switch control like frame. If yes, is there more tag are present which required such switch to operate action further. If possible can you share any reference link where from I can read about it

Comment: @ShubhamJain, In this case `embed` has child `#document`, so it can be handled in the same way as `iframe`. I don't think that there are other similar elements that should be handled in the same way... Maybe `object` also, but I'm not sure